# Java & MongoDB find document by DBRef

Tags: java, mongodb

Anyone can explain to me how can found a document by DBRef ?
I have this models :

```
public class Person {
    @BsonId
    private ObjectId id;
    private String name;
    private DBRef book ;
    // Getter & Setter
} 

public class Book {
    @BsonId
    private ObjectId id ;
    private String name ;
    // Getter and Setter 
}
```

and this Simple Main Class :

```
import com.mongodb.*;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import com.mongodb.client.gridfs.codecs.GridFSFileCodecProvider;
import com.mongodb.client.model.Filters;
import com.mongodb.client.model.geojson.codecs.GeoJsonCodecProvider;
import com.mongodb.connection.ClusterSettings;
import org.bson.codecs.BsonValueCodecProvider;
import org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodecProvider;
import org.bson.codecs.ValueCodecProvider;
import org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecProvider;
import org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistries;
import org.bson.codecs.pojo.PojoCodecProvider;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;

import java.util.List;

import static com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings.getDefaultCodecRegistry;
import static org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistries.fromProviders;

public class MainClass {
    private static final String HOST = "127.0.0.1";
    private static final int PORT = 27017;
    private static final String USERNAME = "admin";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "adminpass";
    private static final String DATABASE = "tutorial";

    private static final List<CodecProvider> codecProviderList = List.of(
            new ValueCodecProvider(),
            new BsonValueCodecProvider(),
            new DocumentCodecProvider(),
            new DBRefCodecProvider(),
            new DBObjectCodecProvider(),
            new BsonValueCodecProvider(),
            new GeoJsonCodecProvider(),
            getDefaultCodecRegistry(),
            fromProviders(PojoCodecProvider.builder().automatic(true).build()),
            new GridFSFileCodecProvider());
    private static final MongoDatabase mongoDatabase;

    private static void getHosts(ClusterSettings.Builder builder) {
        builder.hosts(List.of(new ServerAddress(HOST, PORT)));
    }

    private static MongoClient createMongoClient() {
        MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createCredential(USERNAME, DATABASE, PASSWORD.toCharArray());
        MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
                .applyToClusterSettings(MainClass::getHosts)
                .credential(credential)
                .build();
        return MongoClients.create(settings);
    }

    public static MongoDatabase getDatabase(MongoClient mongoClient) {
        return mongoClient.getDatabase(DATABASE)
                .withCodecRegistry(CodecRegistries.fromProviders(codecProviderList));
    }

    static {
        MongoClient mongoClient = createMongoClient();
        mongoDatabase = getDatabase(mongoClient);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MongoCollection<Person> personCollection = mongoDatabase.getCollection("person", Person.class);
        MongoCollection<Book> bookCollection = mongoDatabase.getCollection("book", Book.class);

        /* Insert to database */
/*
        Book book = new Book();
        book.setName("Test Book");
        bookCollection.insertOne(book);


        Person person = new Person();
        person.setName("Mohammad");
        person.setBook(new DBRef("book",book.getId()));
        personCollection.insertOne(person);
*/

        Person person = personCollection.find(Filters.eq("name", "Mohammad")).first();
        ObjectId personObjectId = person.getId();

        Book book = bookCollection.find(Filters.eq("book", new DBRef("person", personObjectId))).first();
        System.out.println(book.getName());
    }
}
```

Why I always receive this error ?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: DBRefCodec does not support decoding
```